# Javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException:

Tags: java

I created A tictactoe (creategame class) game on my mac, uploaded it to GitHub, downloaded on windows 7.
Then this error occurred while running the eclipse project. 
On researching, I think its a software/driver issue or it's not detecting the sound files, as a beginner, I am completely stumped.
 Thanks guys for your help.

```
  Error with playing sound.
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 24 bit, stereo, 6 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.implOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectClip.open(Unknown Source)
    at TicTacToe.CreateGame.playSound(CreateGame.java:157)
    at TicTacToe.CreateGame.actionPerformed(CreateGame.java:200)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

    public void playSound() {
//       Load sounds


            try {
                AudioInputStream A = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/A3_04.wav"));
                AudioInputStream Bb = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Bb4_01.wav"));
                AudioInputStream C = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/C5_01.wav"));
                AudioInputStream D = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/D4_01.wav"));
                AudioInputStream E = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/E4_01.wav"));
                AudioInputStream F = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/F4_01.wav"));
                AudioInputStream G = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/G4_01.wav"));




    //          IR and IR2 = random number max 7

                AudioInputStream[] Sounds = { C, D, E, F, G, A, Bb };

                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                Clip clip2 = AudioSystem.getClip();

                clip.open(Sounds[IR]);
                clip2.open(Sounds[IR2]);

                clip.start();
                clip2.start();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

[Screenshot of eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLoTa.png)

Thank you very much for your help :P

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PlaySound {

public PlaySound() {
    super();
}

@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void playSound() {
    AudioStream Sounds = null;

        try {
            InputStream a3 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("A3_04.wav");
            InputStream bB4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Bb4_01.wav");
            InputStream c4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("C5_01.wav");
            InputStream d4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("D4_01.wav");
            InputStream e4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("E4_01.wav");
            InputStream f4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("F4_01.wav");
            InputStream g4 = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("G4_01.wav");


                     AudioStream a = new AudioStream(a3);
                     AudioStream b = new AudioStream(bB4);
                     AudioStream c = new AudioStream(c4);
                     AudioStream d = new AudioStream(d4);
                     AudioStream e = new AudioStream(e4);
                     AudioStream f = new AudioStream(f4);
                     AudioStream g = new AudioStream(g4);

                    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() *6); 

                    if (randomNumber == 0) {Sounds = a; }
                    if (randomNumber == 1) {Sounds = b; }
                    if (randomNumber == 2) {Sounds = c; }
                    if (randomNumber == 3) {Sounds = d; }
                    if (randomNumber == 4) {Sounds = e; }
                    if (randomNumber == 5) {Sounds = f; }
                    if (randomNumber == 6) {Sounds = g; }

             AudioPlayer.player.start(Sounds);



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Hardware issues that conflicted with audioinputstream, replace to audiostream